# How to Post particular row data to server in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I am fetching the contacts from the device successfully into my list page. but I am unable to post that particular contact name and number to the server.can any one help for this task in ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .ts file import following:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   let data = { name: "abc", number: 123 };
   let body = JSON.stringify(data);
   let head = new HttpHeaders();
   head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
   head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
   this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
   this.http.post('YOUR_URL', body, {headers: head}).toPromise().then(response=>{
  console.log("------ Success -------"+response);
});
  }
```

As shown above i import http to use http methods and header also sometimes it may happen that it gives CORS error and also define content-type of header.

Comment: Thanks @Husain... Its working

Comment: you most welcome